# how to changed button color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am trying to change button color on pressed but its not working

```
Expanded(child:  RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Civilian"),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
            color: pressAttention ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
              // 3
              onPressed: () => {

                setState(() {

                  pressAttention = !pressAttention;
                  print(pressAttention);


                })
              },

            ),
            ),
```

note: I defined pressAttention var above

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize your variable above `@override`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool pressAttention = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Civilian"),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            color: pressAttention ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
            // 3
            onPressed: () => {
              setState(() {
                pressAttention = !pressAttention;
                print(pressAttention);
              })
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried and is not working, can I show to you my full code?

Comment: have you tried the code above...try to run the simple code first, maybe theres issue somewhere.

Comment: I'm using Stack body and children widget. I`m new on flutter so I dont know my issue

Comment: i think its better to show the full code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: but how ? email or where?

Comment: @iKaka Your can Share the code for that file only, which is having issues in color changing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you restart the app and see if it works? Because usage of stateful widget requires hot restart to be able to see the changes, hot reload won't work here.

Comment: I tried and is not working, can I show to you my full code?

Answer (score 0):

**use highlightColor in RaisedButton**

example

```
Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Civilian"),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                highlightColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
```